# IMongoQueryable throwing error with AutoMapper .ProjectTo() method

Tags: c#, automapper, mongodb-.net-driver

The code below gives this error. I recently switched to MongoDb instead of Ef Core. It seems like automapper doesn't get the object inside it but a serialized form "{document}"  or anything else. Can't find much about this and also debugged the automapper code but cannot seem to figure out why this happens.

Error:

> GetPartyFullName of type Application.Read.Common.Helpers.MapHelpers is
> not supported in the expression tree GetPartyFullName({document}).

```
var partiesList = await parties
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Name) // this is IOrderedMongoQueryable
            //.AsQueryable() => not working either
            .ProjectTo<PartyDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .PaginatedListAsync(request.PageNumber, request.PageSize);
```

The mapping

```
... code
profile.CreateMap<Party, PartyDto>()
            .ForMember(d => d.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => MapHelpers.GetPartyFullName(s)));
... more code
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `.ProjectTo` extension automapper will translate it to `select` operation.

According to docs: `The .ProjectTo<OrderLineDTO>() will tell AutoMapper’s mapping engine to emit a select clause to the IQueryable...`.

So most likely mongo db query translator just does not support your `MapHelpers.GetPartyFullName` function. Try to rewrite your mapping directly in the `.MapFrom(...)` call.

Comment: Doesn't even work with this: .ForMember(d => d.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => $"{s.Name.ToUpper()} {s.Firstname}")); 

Error: Format of type System.String is not supported in the expression tree Format(\"{0} {1}\", {document}{Name}.ToUpper(), {document}{Firstname}).

Comment: @Jesse mongoDb driver does not know about `string.Format`. Just replace on `opt.MapFrom(x => s.Name.ToUpper() + " " + s.Firstname)`. All supported operation you can find [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/expressions/)

Comment: That works! Thanks, didn't know it was not supported. How about getting a first item out of a collection which is under the main aggregate. Like "opt.MapFrom(s => s.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == AddressType.Main).City)" this will obviously not work either. So how can it be done with automapper/mongo? Thank you!